# Convert CURSOR into SELECT - Send parent table value to joined table returning function as a parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

Currently this cursor takes lots of times to execute. And I believe that the best solution is converting the cursor into `SELECT` statement. I have implemented a bit of select statement but unable to send parent table's value to second table returning function as a parameter. Do you have any idea how I can get the exact same result with `SELECT` statement?

Here's the original `CURSOR` implementation

```sql
declare @orgusers table (UserID int, PRIMARY KEY (UserID))
                delete from @orgusers
                declare curOrgs CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
                    select distinct ('~' + qlu.MemberValue + '~') as curOrgs                    
                    FROM [gl].VTN_QualificationMemberLU qlu 
                    where qlu.MemberType = 45 and qlu.QualificationID = 1111
                open curOrgs
                FETCH NEXT FROM curOrgs INTO @org
                while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                begin
                    insert into @orgusers(UserID) 
                    SELECT distinct u.UserID
                    FROM [gl].[GetStudentsByOUPath_BeforeCutoff](@nCompanyid, @org, @dCutOffDate) as u
                    left join @orgusers ou on ou.UserID = u.UserID
                    where ou.UserID is null
                    fetch next from curOrgs INTO @org
                end 
                close curOrgs
                deallocate curOrgs
```

I'm looking for a way that how can I convert this `CURSOR` into `SELECT` statement to get the same `IDs` in `@orgusers TABLE`.

Scenario to repro.

qlu.MemberValue returns data from the table called `VTN_QualificationMemberLU` something like - `2343-2987-2783-2873`

So based on MemberValue function called `GetStudentsByOUPath_BeforeCutoff` returns a table based on some logic containing something like
`2343 2783 2873`

and we put this Ids into @orgUsers table and return as a result of the function.

So based on requirement - `VTN_QualificationMemberLU` table has 10 data. And we need to return 30 ID back by filtering using the function
called `GetStudentsByOUPath_BeforeCutoff`. For each row of the `VTN_Qual....` we need to return 3 Ids as a table result.

Here's the test scripts to repro.

```sql
CREATE TABLE VTN_QualificationMemberLU (
    MemberValue  nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
)


INSERT INTO VTN_QualificationMemberLU (MemberValue) VALUES 
('2385-3772-3764-2918'),
('2385-3772-3764-2918'),
('2382-1237-1203-2367'),
('2123-1238-8123-1232'),
('1238-1222-9982-7129'),
('2385-3772-3764-2918'),
('5645-1232-1203-1232'),
('6675-1238-5655-1232'),
('1238-1233-1232-1231')



CREATE FUNCTION GetStudentsByOUPath_BeforeCutoff  (
    @userIds NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
    SELECT value  
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@userIds, '-')  
    WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';
```

So for each row of the `VTN_Quali...` table we need to call function and need to collect that table result of the function.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Please provide information that is need to reproduce the scenario, meaning queries to create the relevant table and to insert some sample data. In addition please describe the expeted result set according to the sample data

Comment: @RonenAriely I just tried to explain the scenario to repro

Comment: Less explanation (stories) and more code which we can execute in order to reproduce the scenario in seconds - will fit better and will let us waste less time and provide faster solution while helping to other people on the same time. Please provide full demo scenario which we can execute instead (or in addition) to the attempt to describe the tables. We need queries to create the relevant table and insert some sample data as starting point. personally I usually do not even read the entire question without this information.

Comment: @RonenAriely Now I have adjusted and added some test scripts which you can use to repro the issue. I have explained the issue in the last sentence. Thanks.

Comment: This is done using `CROSS APPLY`. For example using your sample table and data you can execute: `SELECT * from VTN_QualificationMemberLU CROSS APPLY GetStudentsByOUPath_BeforeCutoff (MemberValue)`

Answer (score 0):

> Here's the test scripts to repro.

I ignore the description before this since we do not ahve the DDL+DML to reprodcue the full scenario so let's focus on your sample table and data

```
-- DDL+DML
CREATE TABLE VTN_QualificationMemberLU (
    MemberValue  nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO VTN_QualificationMemberLU (MemberValue) VALUES 
('2385-3772-3764-2918'),
('2385-3772-3764-2918'),
('2382-1237-1203-2367'),
('2123-1238-8123-1232'),
('1238-1222-9982-7129'),
('2385-3772-3764-2918'),
('5645-1232-1203-1232'),
('6675-1238-5655-1232'),
('1238-1233-1232-1231')
GO

CREATE FUNCTION GetStudentsByOUPath_BeforeCutoff  (
    @userIds NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
    SELECT value  
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@userIds, '-')  
    WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';
GO
```

In order to execute the table's function on all the rows in existing table we can use `CROSS APPLY`

For example:

```
SELECT t1.MemberValue,t2.[value]
from VTN_QualificationMemberLU t1
CROSS APPLY GetStudentsByOUPath_BeforeCutoff (MemberValue) as t2
```

Obviously, if you need only the clean values from the function then you can return only the column `t2.[value]`

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's really not possible to for me to test this because there's so many discrepancies (missing variables, columns, etc.) between your question code and your example code & data, but here is what it probably should look like.  I have just commented out the cursor code in-place so that you can better see how to do the transformation of the code from cursor to set-based:

```
declare @orgusers table (UserID int, PRIMARY KEY (UserID))
delete from @orgusers

--declare curOrgs CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
;WITH cte AS
(   select distinct ('~' + qlu.MemberValue + '~') as curOrgs                    
    FROM [gl].VTN_QualificationMemberLU qlu 
    where qlu.MemberType = 45 and qlu.QualificationID = 1111
)
--open curOrgs
--FETCH NEXT FROM curOrgs INTO @org
--while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
--begin
    insert into @orgusers(UserID) 
    SELECT distinct u.UserID
    FROM cte AS c
    CROSS APPLY [gl].[GetStudentsByOUPath_BeforeCutoff](@nCompanyid, c.curOrgs, @dCutOffDate) as u
    left join @orgusers ou on ou.UserID = u.UserID
    --where ou.UserID is null
    --fetch next from curOrgs INTO @org
--end 
--close curOrgs
--deallocate curOrgs
```

I think that you can probably get rid of the `distinct` in the CTE (you shouldn't need two DISTINCT's and the later one will do the work of both).